# Can I link a FogBugz ticket to a Trello card in Trello?

Tags: trello, fogbugz

Can I link FogBugz cases to Trello cards and/or items on a Trello card checklist?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Put the URL of the case in a comment on the card.